# Solving an equation with residue classes?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

I want to show that in ℤ<sub>6</sub>, the equation

```
[2]X = [0]
```

has a solution, but the equation

```
[2]X = [5]
```

does not. However, I am unsure how to find the solution to X, specifically, how to divide residue classes? I know that how addition and multiplication work for residue classes, but not division.

Comment: Have you tried computing examples? Fortunately, $\mathbb{Z}_6$ only has $6$ elements.

Comment: https://www.prestonchild.com/books/riptide/  is really good. Before they started the Pendergast series. https://www.prestonchild.com/books/series/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just list all the $2a$ values.

$2*0 \equiv 0$ and $2*1 \equiv 2$ and $2*2 \equiv 4$ and $2*3 \equiv 0$ and $2*4 \equiv 2$ and $2*5 \equiv 4$.

So $2x \equiv 0,2,4$ all have two solutions and $2x \equiv 1,3,5$ have no solutions.

A bit more sophisticated: $2x \equiv 0 \mod 6$ means $6|2x$ which means there is an integer $k$ so that $2x = 6k$ or $x = 3k$ so we con have $x \equiv 0,3$.

$2x \equiv 6 \mod 6$ means $6|2x - 5$ so there is an integer $k$ so that $2x -5 = 6k$.  Or $2x = 6k -5$ so $x = 3k - \frac 52$.  $\frac 52$ is not an integer so $x$ is never an integer.

A lot more sophisticated:  $mx \equiv a \mod n$ means $n|mx - a$ which means $\frac n{\gcd(n,m)}\mid \frac m{\gcd(n,m)}x - \frac a{\gcd(n,m)}$ so unless $\gcd(n,m)|a$ there will be no solution.

Thus as $\gcd(2,6) = 2$ and $2\not \mid 5$ there can not be any solution to $2x \equiv 5$ as $2$ will always divide $2x$ but will never divide $6k + 5$.

If $\gcd(n,m)|a$ and $\frac a{\gcd(n,m)} = b$ then there is a solution as $\gcd(\frac m{\gcd(n,m)}, \frac n{\gcd(n,m)}) = 1$ and for two number being relatively prime $\frac m{\gcd(n,m)}x - \frac n{\gcd(n,m)}k = b$ will always have a solution by Bezout's lemma.

So $2x \equiv 0 \mod 6$ will have as as $\gcd(2,6) =2$ and $\gcd(2,6)|0$.